# AngularJS Directive names

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm currently following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@tweededbadger/tutorial-dynamic-data-driven-svg-map-with-angularjs-b112fdec421d#.tk8zc63b6

He created a directive for 'svgMap'

```
angular.module('SvgMapApp').directive('svgMap', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'img/Blank_US_Map.svg',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}
}]);
```

that returns a template (the svg file) and to use it, in index.html, he then used `<div svg-map></div>`

I'm a little confused about the usage of the directive. How come 'svgMap' was automatically linked to 'svg-map'? Sorry, I'm a newbie when it comes to directives.

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes are not case sensitive, meaning that "svgMap" and "svgmap" is the same attribute.

Angular has naming [`convention for directives`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) when you use in HTML

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant